# how to iterate though delimited values in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, sed, while-loop

BASH

input: cat test

```
  1 a;b;c;d
  2 a;b;c;d
  3 a;b;c;d
```

desired output is:

```
  1 a
  1 b
  1 c
  1 d
  2 a
  2 b
  2 c
  2 d
  3 a
  3 b
  3 c
  3 d
```

it could be something quite simple for programmers.
thank you.

Comment: It sounds like this is a two-part question. You should search for doing loops on files in bash and secondly, how to filter each line. Do a little research, try some things. Showing your work here that you have already tried will go a long way.

Comment: [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) is rather directly on-point, in terms of being a *literal* guide on iterating through delimited values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Solution 1st:*** Could you please try following.

```
awk -F'[ ;]' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){print $1,$i}}' Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Adding another `awk` too now.

```
awk '{gsub(/;/,ORS $1 OFS)} 1'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^((\s*\S+\s*)[^;]*);/\1\n\2/;P;D' file
```

Replace each `;` by a newline followed by the key.

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward shell:

```
IFS=" ;"
shopt noglob # or set -f
while read -r line; do 
  set -- $line; a=$1; shift
  for b; do printf '%s %s\n' "$a" "$b"; done
done
# if data never contains backslash can omit -r from read
# if data never contains glob patterns (? * [..] etc) can omit set -f
# if data never contains backslash and first col never begins with hyphen
# can replace printf with echo "$a" "$b"
```

Clever shell, *if* first column never contains percent or backslash:

```
IFS=" ;"
shopt noglob # or set -f
while read -r line; do 
  set -- $line; a=$1; shift
  printf "$a %s\n" "$@"
done
# read -r and set -f as above
```

Both of these leave IFS and (maybe) noglob changed; if this is all or the last part of a script, or a function using (), those changes are to a local instance and discarded. Otherwise either explicitly save and restore, or surround with () so they are discarded.

Similarly both clobber the positional arguments, which generally matters only when in a script or function; if those are needed subsequently, save and restore them, or alternatively in bash or ksh only use a separate explicit array variable:

```
IFS=" ;"
shopt noglob # or set -f
while read -ra ary; do
  a=${ary[0]}; unset ary[0]
  for b in "${ary[@]}"; do printf '%s %s\n' "$a" "$b"; done
  # or 
  printf "$a %s\n" "${ary[@]}"
done
```